# align buttons vertically in ul tag

Tags: html, css

I want to align buttons vertically. which are placed inside ul tag here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/degHp/ ...i want middle button to be vertically centered and also the text inside button to be centered vertically ..anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did.

- Added `display:block` and `vertical-align:middle` on each li element
- Added `line-height` to each li.  This vertically aligns the text inside the link.
- Removed your `margin-top:10px` from small li because it no longer needs it.

http://jsfiddle.net/degHp/8/